# UWP how to get access to file in folder

Tags: file, uwp

Help me please, I can't  get access to file which I choose by  FileOpenPicker.

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
openPicker.CommitButtonText = "Открыть";
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xlsx");
var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{

}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of how UWP sandboxes access to the filesystem, you can't construct a `FileStream` directly from a `StorageFile`'s path. Instead, you have a few options, in order from simplest to most complex:

1) If your file is small enough, you can just use the helpers in the `FileIO` static class to read it all at once:

```cs
string text =  await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file); // or ReadLinesAsync or ReadBufferAsync, depending on what you need
```

2) Use the `OpenAsync()` method on StorageFile:

```cs
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read, StorageOpenOptions.AllowReadersAndWriters)) 
{
     // your reading code here
}
```

If you need to, you can convert between `IRandomAccessStream` and .NET `Stream`s with the `AsStream()`, `AsStreamForRead()` and `AsStreamForWrite()` extension methods on `IRandomAccessStream`, the [docs for which are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-convert-between-dotnet-streams-and-winrt-streams).

3) If you want complete control, you can get a `SafeFileHandle` to the underlying file using `CreateSafeFileHandle()`, like so:

```cs
SafeFileHandle fileHandle = file.CreateSafeFileHandle(FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

You can then use this file handle to create a standard `FileStream`:

```cs
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.Read))
{
     // Read stuff here
}
```

This is the only way to reliably use a `FileStream` on a UWP `StorageFile`, and should be used with some caution. The official docs have more details on [the implications of doing this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.windowsruntimestorageextensions.createsafefilehandle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Answer (score 1):

`FileOpenPicker` gives you a `StorageFile` which wraps the opened files and gives you permission to it. This doesn't give you access to the file in general - e.g. you cannot use its `Path` only to open it with a `FileStream`. Instead, you need to use the respective `Windows.Storage` APIs to do this. I usually use the `OpenStreamForReadAsync` extension method. Add `using System.IO` to the file header and then:

```
var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

This method returns a `System.IO.Stream` which you can use with classic `System.IO`-enabled APIs.

Comment: I was having the same issue when working on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-access-file-data/5-exercise-upload-files-onedrive) tutorial from MS Graph team (they should make the correction there). Your suggestion resolved my issue. But now I have different issue on the next line of the same code - that I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62725442/1232087) - in case you have some time for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid use file `Path` to access file stream in UWP platform, if you have get the file with `FileOpenPicker`. You could get the file stream with following.

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
openPicker.CommitButtonText = "Открыть";
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xlsx");
var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{      
 var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
}
```

And if you need use stream in `System.IO` namespace. please call `AsStream` method for `IRandomAccessStream` object.

```
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
System.IO.Stream iostream = stream.AsStream();
```

For more detail please refer this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).