# C# UWP Read and write files: Access denied

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating an UWP application to split CSV and Excel files. The user has to select a file in any folder on the machine and the application has to read the file. At the end of the process, the application has to save one or more files based on what the user wants.

When I try to read a CSV file with this code

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
    return csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
}
```

I receive an error

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\enric\Downloads\combined_data.csv' is denied.'

[image]

I checked the capabilities in the `Package.appxmanifest` but there is none related to files or folders. There is only `Removable Storage` that seems similar to what I'm looking for but it doesn't work.

[image]

In the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions), I read to add a custom capability

```
<Capabilities><uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/></Capabilities>
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877741/access-to-the-path-is-denied   This link may be helpful

Comment: Thank you @JackArnold but that post is related to IIS not UWP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60945529/uwp-how-to-get-access-to-file-in-folder is relevant - you don't have access to the path directly, but you can get a stream from the StorageFile returned from the FileOpenPicker. If the user's explicitly picking files you don't need any special capabilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UWP how to get access to file in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60945529/uwp-how-to-get-access-to-file-in-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify capabilities, just use pick file or read file code, this code can be also found in Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers?WT.mc_id=WDIT-MVP-5003917) and [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files?WT.mc_id=WDIT-MVP-5003917#reading-from-a-file).

```
private async void Btn_OpenFile_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
                picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");
                picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

                var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
                if (file != null)
                {
                    
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is if I want to use the file when I use the `FileOpenPicker`. I want to open the file later or in a procedure in background.

Comment: Maybe you can try `FutureAccessList`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38107910/7068790